# Is format-number supported by the MS .net xpath implementation?

Tags: c#, xpath, visual-studio-2015

I ran this code in linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    //XElement doc = XElement.Load(new StringReader("<item><name>Some Name</name></item>"));
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(@"<value>133445</value>");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
    Evaluate(doc, "/value/text()").Dump();
    Evaluate(doc, "format-number(/value/text(), '###,##0.00')").Dump(); 
}

private static string Evaluate(XDocument e, string expression)
{
    object o = e.XPathEvaluate(expression);
    var objects = o as IEnumerable<object>;
    if (objects != null)
    {
        return objects.FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
    }

    return o?.ToString();
}
```

And the output is:

```
133445

XPathException:
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.
```

Calling format-number fails with the exception above. Is there another way to format a number using xpath functions?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like `format-number()` is an [XPath 3.0 function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-format-number). In this case, you need XPath engine that supports XPath 3.0, for example, Saxon for .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

format-number() was originally defined in XSLT 1.0 as an XSLT-specific function (therefore not available in XPath 1.0), and it remained that way in the 2.0 versions of the specs. Finally with XPath 3.0 it found its way into XPath.